# Limit number of Dynamic list Items in a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to achieve 2 things with this Code I have been working on so not sure if to separate the Questions:

JS:

```
function listPosts(data) {
    postlimit = 
    var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
    $.each(data.posts,function(key,val) {   

        output += '<li>';
        output += '<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')">';
        output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
        output += '<p>' + excerpt + '</p>';
        output += '</a>';
        output += '</li>';
    }); // go through each post
    output+='</ul>';
    $('#postlist').html(output);
} // lists all the posts
```

Questions:

1: I would like to limit the number of Dynamic List Posts returned to 8

2: While I limit the displayed items, I want to add a 'More...' text at the bottom so another set of 8 items is appended to already displayed list.

I am already trying out some codes but was hoping to get some guidance

Comment: Are you fetching the results from a database? Because you can easily `LIMIT` it to 8 there

Comment: Result is coming from JSON API: <script src="http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=recentstories&callback=listPosts" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I can limit it from my wordpress panel or just adding at the end of the json URL call but was hoping this can be done with a function

Answer (score 1):

I am answering you on basis of pure logic and implementation of logic. there could be API stuff for it , but I don't really know. Secondly; It would be a good solution to find some jQuery plugin if you don't have any problems with using jQuery.

call the function `onMoreClick()` upon clicking the `More...` html item

```
  var end = 8;
  var start = 1;

  function onMoreClick()
  {
     start = end 
     end = end+8;
     listPosts(data)
  }

  function listPosts(data) {
    postlimit = 
    var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
    var i = start;
    $.each(data.posts,function(key,val) {   
        if(i<end && i >=start){
        output += '<li>';
        output += '<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')">';
        output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
        output += '<p>' + excerpt + '</p>';
        output += '</a>';
        output += '</li>';
        i++;
       }
    }); // go through each post
    output+='</ul>';
    $('#postlist').html(output);
} // lists all the posts
```

Comment: Thanks Tauseef, will try your suggestion also

Answer (score 1):

```
function listPosts(data, postlimit) {
    var $output = $('<ul class="posts" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">');

    $.each(data.posts,function(key, val) {   
        $("<li>", {id: "post_" + val.id})
            .append([
                $("<h3>", {text: val.title}),
                $("<p>", {text: val.excerpt})
            ])
            .appendTo($output);

        return (postlimit-- > 1);
    });

    $('#postlist').empty().append($output);
}

// exemplary delegated event handler
$(document).on("click", "ul.posts h3", function () {
    $(this).show();
});
```

later ...

```
listPosts(data, 8);
```

Notes:

- from `$.each()` you can return `true` or `false`. If you return `false`, the loop stops.
- Try not to build HTML from concatenated strings. This is prone to XSS vulnerabilities that are easy to avoid. jQuery gives you the tools to build HTML safely.
- Generally, for the same reason, try to avoid working with `.html()`, especially if you already have DOM elements to work with.
- Don't use inline event handlers like `onclick`. At all. Ever.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for the heads up and will try your suggestion, much appreciated

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but I am only getting one output and the HTML CSS showing in the one result: They didn&#8217;t Bow; They didn&#8217;t Burn <p>THEY DIDN&#8217;T BOW; THEY DIDN&#8217;T BURN &#8211;

Comment: like I earlier mentioned, your Code looks promising but I am unable to get it to work. Can you help?

Comment: Please build a jsFiddle that reproduces your situation. "I can't get it to work" is nothing I can act on.

Comment: this is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c9p2A/19/) but its not loading as it should when you access the [link](http://howtodeployit.com/newdevotion/) directly

Comment: You should start with looking at the JavaScript console of your browser, tracking down and eliminating all the errors you see, one by one. -- Please note that I do not intend to do interactive debugging through the comments here. Try to solve as many errors on your own, building the application bit by bit from scratch, taking only steps that work. That's how I would do it. If you encounter further problems, ask a new question here (after searching - most problems are solved already)

Comment: No problem Tomalak, I am already doing a bit of study and working my way through the Codes. Will update case when I resolve the issue